# How to trim exisiting whitespace at the end of the line using Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

Good day! I am new and exploring Regular expression. I am currently profiling the data and excluding the dirty data in our system. Now, I am having a hard time removing trailing whitespace, I dont know what built-in function should I use to eliminate this. If I put \h it wont capture the space, but if I used \s it captured the space but it has trailing space in the end of the line.

This is my Regular Expression tested on regexp.com

```
\b((\d{1,}[\s|\-]+){1,3}\d{1})\b
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2tZu.png)

The Format I wanna capture are:

```
Format1- ####-#######-# 
Format2- #### ####### #
Format3- ##-#######-#
Format4- ## ####### #
Format5- ########## ({10,12} digits)
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) to your question (no comment).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match those formats, you could match either 2 or 4 digits. Capture matching either a space or `-` in a group, and use a backreference to what is captured in that group to keep the delimiters the same (So not match a space and `-` in the same format)

Note that `\s` could also match a newline. If you want to match spaces only, you could add that instead.

```
\b(?:(?:\d{4}|\d{2})([- ])\d{7}\1\d|\d{10,12})\b
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\d{4}|\d{2})` Match either 4 or 2 digits
  - `([- ])` Capture **group 1**, match either `-` or space (use `\s` to match whitespace char)
  - `\d{7}\1\d` Match 7 digits, backreference to group 1 (match the same char as previous one) followed by the last digit
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{10,12}` Match 10 - 12 digits
- `)` Close group
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gyWaQX/1)

Comment: OMG! Thank you sir for helping me. I am just exploring your code to all the data or format I wanna capture. Big help sir! Lastly, can you pls explain me what is the meaning of non-capture? like (?:)

Comment: Non capture means that it is a group, in this case used for the alternation `|` to match either one of the alternatives. But you can not access it separately when you want to use it in your tool or code or use a backreference to it.